# Notepad++ always in multi instance

Tags: settings, notepad++, multiple-instances

I need Notepad++ running in multiple instance mode without "-multiInst" parameter.
I can't use .lnk shortcuts, I can't use `cmd.exe /c notepad++.exe -multiInst`, is there another way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this would be using a wrapper. Create a file called "np++.bat" with the following content:

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Notepad++" -multiInst %1
```

Put it somewhere in your PATH. You can then invoke it as:

```
np++.bat file.txt
```

Comment: He says he can't use `-multiInst`.

Comment: It worked! It seems that I can use -multiInst with this workaround, I didn't know that... sorry BoltClock; would you have suggested the same?

Comment: @SchurigH: Actually, I would have, so I'll upvote this answer. Anyway, did you look at my edited answer? You can emulate Notepad mode by adding the `asNotepad.xml` file, without the need for a batch file.

Answer (score 13):

If you need [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface)-mode Notepad++, there is no way to force it to start in multi-instance mode without the `-multiInst` parameter.

If you can work with [SDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_document_interface)-mode Notepad++ (like Notepad), it'll default to multi-instance mode just like the default Notepad on Windows: one window per file. To trigger SDI mode, place an empty file called `asNotepad.xml` in `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++`. Be sure to back up your `%AppData%\Notepad++` folder before starting Notepad++ again.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Short question: Which is the best multiple instance editor in your opinion? I need an alternative editor now... :-/

Comment: @SchurigH: Do you need your editor to have each file in its own instance like Notepad?

Comment: Yes, multiple instances for each file, like notepad. I searched for a few more editors and I picked out Notepad 2, phase 5 HTML Editor. But I havn't tested them yet.

Comment: I will test this .xml trick too, thank you. The advantage of batching SDI over .xml is that I can use Notepad++ MDI for my daily work as usual and Notepad in SDI just for Zope developing.

Comment: Quite a bite late, but this is a fantastic answer! It works flawlessly, and does exactly what is asked in the question!

Answer (score 12):

You can also [manually create another instance](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Multiple_Instances) by going to `Run > Open in another instance`.

Comment: Best answer by far

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is a way to do it without the -multiInst parameter:

> create a totally empty file called 'asNotepad.xml' and put it in the
>   Notepad++ directory at the same level as the notepad++.exe file

https://superuser.com/questions/202399/how-to-make-notepad-open-each-file-in-new-window

Comment: Thanks, it works well but I see 2 disadvantages here:
- it seems that Notepad++ opens with just a new document instead of holding the last opened files (which .exe -multiInst does) and
- with the batch script I can choose whether to open/switch to the "normal" instance of Notepad++ (original .exe) or to open a new instance (.bat script).
But it depends on the situation whether these points are relevant or not.

Answer (score 5):

- Settings > Preferences... > Multi-instance
- Click "Always in multi-instance mode"
- Click Close
- Close all Notepad++ programs

It did not work the first two times I tried it. Maybe Notepad++ takes a while to fully exit.

Comment: I am curios why this was down voted. My assumption is that "Always in multi-instance mode" will always open in multiple instance mode and even if opened from command line, this setting will still be valid.  Anybody care to explain?

Comment: At least in April 2017 this works immediately, so imho this is by far the best answer.

Comment: Agreed, now we're october 2017 and this is the best option for me, especially when using in a multi-virtual desktop environment using Windows 10. If this is not set to the proper value, it would switch virtual desktop to where the window of notepad++ was currently located, making it very confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hoi,
in a n++.bat file,  in your path just enter: (for the x86 version )

```
start "N++ Multi Instance" /D"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\" Notepad++ -multiInst %1
```

Then pull the link to that bat file via right mouse click and drag and drop it to your desktop.

Just click on the link/icon and your n++ starts with every click!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Notepad++ not remembering that I had chosen not the "Remember Current Session". I tried hacking the config file, but that didn't work. Then I found out that there is a secret config file in your C:\Users\myuseraccount\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ directory (Windows 7 x64). Mine was empty, meaning who know where the config was really coming from, but I copied over the file with the one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++ and now everything works just like you would expect it to.

Comment: What is the secret config file?

Comment: It's the config file that's in the C:\Users\myuseraccount\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ directory It is only secret because I didn't expect to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

recently I got same problem.

As I think the easiest way is to write simple .bat file something like this:

...

```
SET var1="C:\Users\churaev.s\Desktop\a01_strt.bat"
SET var2="C:\Users\churaev.s\Desktop\b02_code.mat"

SET var3="C:\Users\churaev.s\Desktop\c03_data.txt"

...

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %var1%

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %var2%

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %var3%

...
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to right-click a tab and "open in new window"... voilà!